# Maven did not download libs (netbeans)

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

The problem is when I describe all dependencies, Maven should download all necessary libs. Do it with eclipse is: mvn eclipse:eclipse. But what about NetBeans? It seems that Maven did not make it's job, because then I try to write HibernateUtil class where I use sessionFactory, the latter is not found and looks like this:
[image]

And then I click to search it in Maven, it shows:

[image]

So how can I make my Maven do it's job and download all necessary libs all alone?

Thanks in advance

### EDITED:

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hibernate.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>FirstHibernate</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
 
        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <!-- Hibernate framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate3</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.GA</version>
    </dependency>
 
 
    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->
 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
 
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run `mvn validate` in your project root (where project `pom.xml` is located) via cmd. If succeeded, it will download all your dependencies into your local repository. Then you should search for maven repository configuration in netbeans options  and make sure that your local repository is added there.

Comment: Yes, it success ( very fast ). Should it show which files were downloaded? Because it shows only : Building Hibernate 1.0-SNAPSHOT, and then SUCCESS.

Comment: And it seems very simple to set repository, but netbeans 7.3.1 has not any repository path in maven option. What I should do? I see that my repository is in my user m2. But how can I set it to netbeans?

Comment: Yes, it should show list downloaded files. Could you show your project's pom.xml? You could manually add dependency on hibernate libs  in pom.xml.

Comment: I added the file : pom.xml. And netbean's version has not any field about repository in maven options..

Comment: Your dependencies seem to be correct, so I guess libs are already downloaded to your local repo. Repository management should be in tab 'services'.

Comment: It's a pity, but there is not any of em: mysql connector, hibernate. What to do? I haven't find any useful sources to solve it..

Comment: Hm, ok. Another thing I could suppose: netbeans uses maven's settings.xml, where your could speciy repositories. It could be located in your user dir or in maven installation directory.

Comment: My repository local path is correct: C:\User\user\m2\repository. But why maven did not download all described libs.

Comment: Nop, versions is not the point. I tried 2 and 3 versions. The result is the same

Comment: Try to compile (mvn compile) your project from cmd. It it fails, the error message will be shown.

Comment: Yes I got an error that some artifacts is missing. Hibernate3. And maven suggests me to download it manually and install it through cmd.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is not the solution, but max_yashin replied some good comments. So this solution is based on that information. Firstly, useful command was : `mvn compile` in my project directory. It shows error about missing artifacts. These artifacts are hibernate3. So, firstly I downloaded `hibernate-3.2.3.Ga.jar` and then (Maven suggested me to) install these missed artifacts manually. So I used this line (adapted with my parameters):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

And it shows a success. When I try to compile Maven again, all errors did not occur,then I typed `mvn validate` (just in case) and it solved my problem. Now I can use Maven in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue i tried using `mvn validate` but it didn't work in my case but then i solved it using `mvn clean install` in terminal where `pom.xml` is located

For more Details :

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheMaven/article.html